# How to correctly do operator overloading in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli

In my class, I have something like this:

```
public ref class Something {
public:
    // some methods

    operator double();
}
```

`Something` wraps something from a third-party DLL which has exactly the same `operator double()` in its header. The compiler now complains about an unresolved token: `MyNamespace.Something::op_Implicit`

How do I have to define this in my implementation?

I tried the following three which did not work:

- `double Something::op_Implicit()` - "op_Implicit is not a member"
- `static double Something::op_Implicit(Something^ s)`- "op_Implicit is not a member"
- `operator Something::double() {...}` - tons of syntax errors

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is not clear. You need to overload the conversion to double?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying.

Comment: [op_Implicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.enterprisemanagement.configuration.managementpackreference.op_implicit.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2)?

Comment: @Hans: Thanks, this is the solution. Could you post this again as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easier to write it inline:

```
public ref class Something {
    double yadayada;
public:
    operator double() { return yadayada; }
};
```

If you don't then the proper syntax is:

```
Something::operator double() {
    return yadayada;
}
```

Which is all okay for usage from C++/CLI code, but if you want to expose the conversion function to other languages then you should declare it *static*:

```
public ref class Something {
    double yadayada;
public:
    static operator double(Something^ arg) {
        return arg->yadayada;
    }
};
```

Prefix the `explicit` keyword to avoid accidental conversion and force the client code to use a cast.

Comment: Your last example works, but instead of `static operator double` I needed to use `static operator Double^` and return a `gcnew Double(arg -> yadayada)` to make it work when referenced in VB.net

Comment: No, that is dead wrong.  Never box a value type.  You did not write a conversion function to double at all, you wrote one for ValueType.  It only works by accident in VB.NET, it won't when you use Option Strict On.  Just plain `double()` works just fine, it is an alias for System::Double.

Comment: The code I posted works fine when used in a VB.NET app, I checked.

Comment: I just tried it again with plain double and you are right, maybe I had a typo the first time I tried it...